# Does the abbreviation "N/A" meaning "Not Applicable" have to be internationalized?

Tags: internationalization

I'm adding i18n to a service.

Should the abbreviation "N/A" meaning "Not Applicable" be internationalized?

Or is "N/A" generally understood.

I think this is an acceptable question because it is about

> - software tools commonly used by programmers [*e.g.* Smartling]; and is
> - a practical, answerable problem that is unique to software development.

Okay, the literal question may not be "unique" to software development, but the question as it pertains to internationalizing a backend service, is.